# 1996 nissan sentra lights come on but wont turnover

Tags: nissan, ignition, starter

Had starter checked and it was working fine. Battery tested it worked fine. Replaced terminals and wires connected to battery. Replaced the connected wire from the battery to starter. My car still won't turnover to start....please help am stumped....also checked fuses..what else could this be? Maybe something with the ignotion?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you hear any clicks when you turn the key? Is there just *nothing*?